# Why can't I match True / False value in an IF statement?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, list, if-statement

I'm trying to match the output of a re.search against a list and run code if the IF statement allows. However, even if I tell the IF statement to match True or False, the IF statement never proceeds.

Running the search in python:

```
>>> re.search(r'...$', 'abcde1234doc').group() in ['doc', 'rtf', 'txt']
>>> True
```

Returns True, so by asking the IF statement to match True, it should proceed with it's code. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
if re.search(r'...$', 'abcde1234doc').group() in ['doc', 'rtf', 'txt'] == True:
    print'regex search matched!'
else:
    print'regex search not matched'
```

I expected the IF statement proceed with it's code when the regex search returns True, however the IF statement doesn't match and goes straight to the ELSE.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the whole expression before `== True`

Comment: You just need `if re.search(r'...$', 'abcde1234doc').group() in ['doc', 'rtf', 'txt']:`.

Comment: Just remove the `== True`

Comment: @Austin oh, that's neat! I will use this in my code

Comment: Basically, since the regex search in list already returns a True/False, I don't need to tell IF what to match since the condition already returns True/False?

Comment: @MrU, exactly. Since the regex search returns a truthy value, this is expected to handle the case.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean operators chain in Python.

```
x in y == z
```

means

```
x in y and y==z
```

You could write your condition as

```
if (re.search(r'...$', 'abcde1234doc').group() in ['doc', 'rtf', 'txt']) == True:
```

if you wanted, but you'd be better off just leaving off the `==True` and sticking with

```
if re.search(r'...$', 'abcde1234doc').group() in ['doc', 'rtf', 'txt']:
```